# Does DependencyInjection support auto registration of services?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Does ASP.Net Core built-in Dependency Injection feature support auto registration of services? I don't want to regester them manually like this:

```
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IUserService), 
                   new UserService(new AtmDbContext())));
```

Comment: How MVC should decide, what your classes should be registered? Some piece of code have to execute `new YouClass`. Moreover you should inform MVC, whether the object should be created once (Singleton) or for example a new instance is created every time (Transient). See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx) for example. And you should have some way to get the reference to the instance of the object (or its interface) in your controller or in the view. Dependency Injection helps to do all this, but you should inform it what you need

Comment: Registration could be a bit simpler: `services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>()`.

Comment: Oleg, have you heard about reflection?

Comment: Oleg is right. You can have 10 different implementations of IUserService. How can reflection help to decide which one you want to use?

Comment: You can use a dependency injection framework like StructureMap which has a ton of additional features, including assembly scanning and conventionbased mapping. https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap.dnx

Answer (score 4):

For my project the following helped me:

In **Startup.cs** method **ConfigureServices** add row:

```
services.AddHandlers("Project name");
```

And implementation of that:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddHandlers(this IServiceCollection services, string assemblyName)
{
      var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), assemblyName + ".dll");
      var assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath));

      var classTypes = assembly.ExportedTypes.Select(t => IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(t)).Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract);

      foreach (var type in classTypes)
      {
          var interfaces = type.ImplementedInterfaces.Select(i => i.GetTypeInfo());

          foreach (var handlerType in interfaces.Where(i => i.IsGenericType))
          {
               services.AddTransient(handlerType.AsType(), type.AsType());
          }
      }

      return services;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got annoyed and built an open-source project for that, take a look:

https://github.com/SharpTools/SharpDiAutoRegister

Just add the nuget package `SharpDiAutoRegister` and add your conventions in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.ForInterfacesMatching("^I[a-zA-z]+Repository$")
        .OfAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .AddSingletons();

services.ForInterfacesMatching("^IRepository")
        .OfAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .AddTransients();

//and so on...
```